# Rx - How to apply to stream distinctUntilChanged that allows emit duplicate item after some period?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming

So, I have to implement some chain or perhaps some custom RxJava operator to an **Observable**, that will distinct items emitted from Observable, until they change, but only for some short period (like 1 sec), then duplicated item can be emitted again.

What I need is some nested combination of **distinctUntilChanged**, with **throttle**?

Main requirements are:

- different items have to be emitted without any delay
- the same item can not be emitted twice in given period

I couldn't find any operator that matches my requirement so, probably I'll need to write some custom Rx operator, but still I can't figure out how to start

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. Do you want to do distinctUntilChanged for about 1 second, then just let everything through?

Comment: @akarnokd just posted my own answer below. check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured out, turned out to be quite easy to implement:

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.distinctUntil(time: Long): Observable<T> {
    return this
        .timestamp()
        .distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
            new.value() == old.value() && new.time() - old.time() < time
        }
        .map { it.value() }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with just `groupBy` operator. Since each `group$` is piped with `throttleTime` and each emission goes through this `group$` Observable it will ignore all subsequent emission for 1s:

```
source$
  .pipe(
    groupBy(item => item.whatever),
    mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(
      throttleTime(1000)
    )),
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```